# Query a different cache inside remote filter for continuous query

Tags: ignite

I have a use case for Ignite's continuous query where I want to set the remote filter such that it evaluates against another cache on the same node. For example:

I start a continuous query on Person cache and use remote filter condition on another cache ("City") such that P.city is present in City cache.

In my use case I control the city cache meaning the user dynamically sets which city he/she is interested in. The city cache will be relatively small (~400) overall. I should mention the filter has to be checking a cache and not use distributed data structure as I need to keep count on the subscription.

Basically, I would like to understand the performance impact of such an approach.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of logic you make there. If you read the documentation, you will see that:

```
Sets optional key-value filter. This filter is called before entry is sent to the master node.
WARNING: all operations that involve any kind of JVM-local or distributed locking (e.g., synchronization or transactional cache operations), should be executed asynchronously without blocking the thread that called the filter. Otherwise, you can get deadlocks.
```

This means that you should avoid blocking or long running operations there. However, the documentation also gives you an answer on how to do this:

```
If remote filter are annotated with IgniteAsyncCallback then it is executed in async callback pool (see IgniteConfiguration.getAsyncCallbackPoolSize()) that allow to perform a cache operations.
```

So to avoid possible performance issues you should use **IgniteAsyncCallback**.